# American Airlines 10-K outstanding shares

Tags: sec, annual-report

The opening paragraphs of [American Airlines 2017 10-K](https://americanairlines.gcs-web.com/node/33206/html) states:

> - there were 473,138,683 shares of *American Airlines Group Inc.* common stock outstanding
> - there were **1,000 shares** of *American Airlines, Inc.* common stock outstanding, all of which were held by *American Airlines Group Inc.*

---

**Why 1,000 shares**?  I read that American Airlines, Inc. is a wholly-owned subsidiary of American Airlines Group Inc. Is this a convention for subsidiaries?

[United Airlines' 10-K](http://otp.investis.com/clients/us/united_continental_holdings/SEC/sec-show.aspx?Type=html&FilingId=12572474&CIK=0000100517&Index=10000) shows an identical situation, where 1,000 shares of United Airlines, Inc. common stock are 100% owned by United Continental Holdings, Inc.

Comment: I'd appreciate if the downvoter could offer an explanation.

Comment: Not my vote, but it's a corporate finance question, while this is a personal finance site.

Comment: @MSalters If it's a question about interpreting information from an annual or quarterly report of a public company, the question may be of relevance to individual investors.

Answer (score -1):

This is a guess: it is probably an older name of the original company, and it was originally traded at a stock exchange.

Creating a new 'publicly traded company' through registration and IPO is an slow and expensive process. Therefore, companies like to keep the existing ones around, and if ever needed (for a carveout or split), rename and reuse the registrations. All they have to do for that is keep a small number of shares in their ownership.
It's called a 'jacket' (translated form German 'Mantel', I don't know the correct english term).

Comment: It's called a Holding Company in English.